# How can I send data via Websocket from a VSCode extension

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, websocket

I would like to send data via Websocket from an VSCode extension. Is there a builtin websocket facility or should I import the package "ws" or else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used ws package, which sadly is not in ES6 module format but otherwise does its job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ws` package, here is an example from the official samples repository: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/lsp-log-streaming-sample/client/src/extension.ts

Comment: That sample is to connect the local websocket server. As what I have tried, I never could connect to `remote` websocket server.  Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/76663420/2602410 .  Have you?