# VSCODE extension could not establish websocket connection with remote websocket server

Tags: websocket, vscode-extensions

I found the websocket in the webview of vscode extension could not establish connection with a `remote` websocket server.

The url I used is like `ws://192.168.5.33:8081`, Developer tools console shows info like

```py
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.5.33:8081/' failed:
```

It does not look like it violates any Content Security Policy, for otherwise, that will be displayed.

Developer tools Network tab shows like just a request, no response. I'm sure websocket server works well, because I run the same code `in browser` instead of vscode webview extension, to connect with that remote server, and found it works well.

Also that extension webview works well with a **local** websocket server, like `ws://127.0.0.1:8081`

Later, I had to move the code of websocket client from webview to extension native with `const WebSocket = require('ws');` to use `ws` lib.

And get failure too.

Again, it worked perfectly to run websocket client in Browser instead of vscode extension to connect remote server.

=================

[Answer my stupid question]

It turns out due to the proxy in vscode set long time ago. By turning the proxy off, everything goes well both in webview and in extension native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out due to the proxy in vscode set long time ago. By turning the proxy off, everything goes well both in webview and in extension native.

Comment: How to turn proxy off? (I don't remember setting it up)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, VS Code applies strict content security policies to webviews. You have to allow explicitly what you need. I have a webview which connects through a websocket to a locally running webserver. My CSP rules are:

```html
<!doctype html><html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src http: https:;
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'unsafe-inline' http: https: data: *;">
...
```

Note: this CSP goes beyond http(s) connections, but also allows inline styles and scripts. So you better review that in detail and only allow what's absolutely necessary!

Comment: Thank you, but my current webview html without  content security policy settings already could connect to local websocket server, it just could not connect to REMOTE websocket server.  I also try with the following setting ending up with no luck:   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content=" default-src * 'self' ws: ; 
    style-src 'unsafe-inline' http: https: data: *;">

Comment: OK, I missed the "remote" part. One would think that it doesn't matter what the target IP address is, right?

Comment: Right, the target IP address does not matter. Have you ever successfully made your vsc extension webview connect to the remote websocket server?